# Deserialize using SimpleModule into Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have a JSON that looks like the below

```
{
    "key1": "1",
    "key2": 2,
    "key3": 3,
    "firstMap": {
        "a": 3,
        "b": 66.67,
        "c": 3,
        "d": true,
        "secondMap": "{\"smKey1\": {\"type\": \"ABC\",\"ABC\": [{\"type\": \"EFG\", \"num\": 100.0 },{\"type\": \"EFG\",\"num\": 50.0},{\"type\": \"JHI\",\"num\": 50.0}]}}"
    }
```

The secondMap needs to be parsed as a Map<String, ABCType> using SimpleModule.

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        SimpleModule typeDeserializerModule = new SimpleModule();
        JavaType collectionType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, ABCType.class);

        TypeReference<Map<String, ABCType>> typeReference =
                new TypeReference<Map<String, ABCType>>() {};
        typeDeserializerModule.addDeserializer((Class<? super Map<String, ABCType>>) collectionType.getRawClass(),
                new Deserializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(typeDeserializerModule);
        return objectMapper;
```

The above code is not giving expected results. This deserializer is being used for all maps and also its not parsing the expected map correctly.

Any leads to parse into Map<String, ABCType> using SimpleModule and deserializer ?

Comment: What does ABCType look like? Is there a constructor or similar that the ObjectMapper is told to use?

Comment: ABCType has just two keys for example { "a" : "1", "b" : "2" } . The problem is that Map<String, ABCType> is stringified and I don't have access to edit the POJO